# Extract folder name one level up and insert to text file using sed

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I have several files under several User(n) folders.

Sample:

User 1 folder directory structure: `/home/Ubuntu/Group1/Team1/User1/01-01-2020/`

```
100510_destination1.ext
100520_destination1.ext
..etc
```

User 2 folder directory structure: `/home/Ubuntu/Group1/Team1/User2/01-01-2020/`

```
103030_sample3.ext
113020_sample3.ext
..etc
```

User (n) folder.. `/home/Ubuntu/Group1/Team1/User(n)/01-01-2020/`

```
112818_any.ext
112918_any.ext
..etc
```

I would like to combine important information from all user(n) files into a text file. Instead of User folder, I'm making a new date folder with all users info in a text file.

For it to look something like below:

Output text log file directory structure: `/home/Ubuntu/Group1/01-01-2020/`

```
10:05:10 Who: User1, To: destination1

10:30:30 Who: User2, To: sample3

11:28:18 Who: User(n), To: any
```

I used printf command to create output file as text.

```
printf '%s\n' * > output.txt

100510_destination1.ext

103030_sample3.ext

112818_any.ext
```

Then run script

`sed 's/./&:/2;s/./&:/5;s/./& To.:/8;s/.//13;s/....$//' output.txt`

I was able to get:

```
10:05:10 To.:destination1

10:30:30 To.:sample3

11:28:18 To.:any
```

But have no idea how to grab the folder name. How do I extract the `User(n)` name which is the folder name one level up and insert it to text? Can it be added on the same command using `sed`? Or more like a `bash` script?

Comment: Please reformat your post. Do you really have a directory named `/Home` not `/home`? Does the filename `01-01-2020

112818_any.ext` has a newline in it? `How do I` You can learn regexes with https://regexcrossword.com/

Comment: @KamilCuk I've reformat my post as requested. Its /home. 01-01-2020 is a folder. Filename under that folder is 112818_any.ext.

Comment: :/ Markdown doesn't preserve newlines. [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Put the content of files also in blocks like source files, ie. prepend with 4 spaces. Is `/home/Ubuntu/Group1/01-01-2020/` part of the text log file? Could you post the directory structure as like the output of `find` command?

Comment: @KamilCuk I see what you mean now, thanks. I've updated my post detailing e.g. `/home/Ubuntu/Group1/01-01-2020/` as directory structure and not part of text log file.

Comment: Why is there no `10:30:20 Who: User2, To: sample3` in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have stored the complete folder path `/Home/Ubuntu/Group1/Team1/User2/01-01-2020` in a bash variable `folderpath`. You can get the `User2` folder name for instance by

```
user_foldername=$(basename "$(dirname "$folderbase")")
```

Answer (score 0):

- First list the file you are interested in
- Then match them with regex
- And substitute with proper replacement

The following:

```
find ./home/Ubuntu/Group1/Team1/ -type f -regex './home/Ubuntu/Group1/Team1/.*/01-01-2020/.*.ext' |
sed 's@.*/\(User[0-9]*\)/[^/]*/\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)_\([^\.]*\).ext$@\2:\3:\4 Who: \1, To: \5@'
```

outputs:

```
10:05:10 Who: User1, To: destination1
10:05:20 Who: User1, To: destination1
10:30:30 Who: User2, To: sample3
11:30:20 Who: User2, To: sample3
11:28:18 Who: User3, To: any
11:29:18 Who: User3, To: any
```

[tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SentimentalIvoryEyestrain#main.sh). You can also add `-maxdepth 7 -mindepth 7` or maybe rewrite the `-regex` to your liking.

> how to grab the folder name.

Using `s/./soemthing/5` looks lame for the flexibility the regex gives you. Regex is not for replacing nth character, it's for matching input. Just match the `/` from the back or from the front count times and that way grab the folder name. So `^./[^/]*/[^/]*/\([^/]*\)/[^/]*/[^/]*$` could save the 3rd folder from the back in a backreference in `sed`. Note that in substitute command any character can be used as parts separator, ie. `sed 's/a/b/'` is the same as `sed 's~a~b~` or `sed 's#a#b#'`.

> How do I extract the User(n) name which is the folder name one level up and insert it to text?

Match it with a regex, replace with a backreference.

> Can it be added on the same command using sed? Or more like a bash script?

As long as you need to parse one line of input at a time `sed` is usually simple enough. For anything more complicated, try `awk`.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk for the explanation and sample command. That's what I was looking for exactly. It did not work at first with error: ````find: b€˜/home/Ubuntu/Group1/Team1/b€™: No such file or directory````. I removed the "." from ````./home ```` which is ````find /home/Ubuntu/Group1/Team1/ -type f -regex '/home/Ubuntu/Group1/Team1/.*/01-01-2020/.*.ext' |
sed 's@.*/\(User[0-9]*\)/[^/]*/\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)_\([^\.]*\).ext$@\2:\3:\4 Who: \1, To: \5@' | sort ```` and added sort as well.

Comment: I don't know if I should create another post for this but how can I run this script per the date folder if the date folder is variable as it is added daily per user. When i run sed script into an output text file ````>output.txt ```` it shows all ```*.ext``` even from other date folders.